# Had to cancel shift and now been removed from roster

Tags: hiring-process, contractors, scheduling

I'm not sure what to call it but for work I go around to different locations and promote various products to increase sales (so usually I'm giving out free samples and educating customers). There are several agencies I am on the roster for and need them to get the work.

I had to cancel on one agency (see [previous question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/109975)) but gave more than a week's notice and had my contact ask if they needed him cover my shift. He was told it was already covered.

They informed me they have removed me from their roster until I provide "documentation" I was unable to make the shift. I explained my other work conflicted and asked what type of documentation they wanted. They replied:

> How can we be sure that if we book you again, you wont have the same
>   issue come up (your other job requiring you to work, and thus you have
>   to cancel)? We just cant be booking and replacing people on shifts,
>   once you commit to a shift with us we need it to be priority.

To be honest this agency pays below standard, but I would like to keep on their roster as:

1. They have work on days that most agencies don't have
2. They make their schedule more in advanced than others.

What should I reply?

> I understand the importance of having reliable people to work with,
>   and how finding a replacement is inadequate. I can provide
>   references who could vouch for my reliability. This was a one time exception
>   If you put me back on
>   the roster I can guarantee I'll make it to the next one!

Is this good?

They keep referring to their policy states that without documentation you get dropped from their roster. This is completely wrong as I carefully read all their policies. But I guess I won't bring it up.

I realized this could happen when I cancelled. I am not bothered by it, as now I'm working the other job that pays better (which I value more than knowing my schedule farther in advance), but for the reasons listed above I would like to keep in contact with this agency too. This was the first time something like this happened.

Comment: Are you _actually_ going to guarantee that you'll make the next one?

Comment: Telling them that you had another job that is more important than theirs, will never go down well. From an employers point of view I can understand their reasoning. How you reply is going to be tricky, for one thing I would not state that you will guarantee any future jobs, what would you do in the event of Ill health or other mitigating circumstances. Instead I would change "I can guarantee" to "I will prioritise"

Comment: Seems inconsistent. You are not bothered you got dropped because you got a better paying gig but you can guarantee it will not happen again.

Comment: @paparazzo I just want to keep them as a backup option. So I would do it again in similar circumstances HOWEVER those circumstances have only come up once.

Answer (score 17):

You did not have to cancel.  You chose to cancel.

You can't have your cake and eat it too. One thing you like is advanced schedule but then you cancelled. If you are going to sign up for job to lock in some days you should honor.

Cancel because you got a better contract is not a valid reason in their mind.  It does not need to be in the policy manual you received.

Apologize and tell them you realize it was wrong to not meet your commitment and ask for another chance.

When you cancelled you should have considered a possible consequence was them taking you off the schedule.

Understand if everyone would cancel for better pay it would kill them.

Comment: I understand the situation but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how should I reply to get back on the roster? I already apologized when I told them I had to cancel.

Comment: Since you apologized once you should not have to apologize again?

Comment: It's not about apology. It's about how you ensure that this will not happen again. You created extra work for them and they'd rather work with people who do not do this. Your job is now to convince them that this will never happen again (and of course to make sure that it does not happen again).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs it's not about that either, it's about how I will *convince* them "that this will not happen again". Hence this question. I'm looking for a script.

Comment: @Bertelem The problem with a "script" is that it does not really work if they are perceptive people. An apology must be heartfelt, and sincere, and it must radiate a true commitment to insight that one was wrong and  one really does not want to ever repeat the mistake again. There is no "script". If the apology is just going through the motions, perceptive people will pick it up and take it as what it is: indifferent and inconsequential. If I were on the other side, I would prefer no apology to one that is just put on.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs this 'apology' is definitely not heart felt. They did some other shady things that I won't get into since I'm not looking for an argument, but to me this is just business.